# Check alphabetical order of vowelList

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check to see if the vowels in a word are in alphabetical order, if not discard the word. 
I've currently selected the vowels out of the word and added them to a string;

```
foreach(char c in word[I])
{
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u')
    {
        vowelList.Add(c)
    }
}
```

how can I check through this list to ensure they are in order without having to compare every character against every other character?

Comment: You don't need to compare every char vs char. You just need to iterate through the chars of the string, store a vowel to temp, and if there already is a char stored in temp, compare to see if the new char is a greater value than the old char in temp. O(n) solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ like:

```
bool IsOrdered = vowelList.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual(vowelList);
```

You list `vowelList` will contain characters in the order from your character array, if you sort them using `OrderBy` the should be same as your original list.

Apart from that you can also modify your check as:

```
if (new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }.Contains(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work efficiently:

```
private static readonly char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
public static bool AreVowelsInAlphabeticalOrder(string word)
{
    int lastIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    { 
        char c = word[i];
        int vowelIndex = Array.IndexOf(vowels, c);
        if(vowelIndex >= 0)
        {
            if(vowelIndex < lastIndex)
                return false;
            else
                lastIndex = vowelIndex;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it something like this using LINQ:

```
// This list is to keep track of which letters are vowels
var vowels = new List<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

// This is the word we want to check the order of
string word = "testing"; // gives true

// We start of by finding all vowels in the word (in the order they appear)
var vowelList = word.Where(letter => vowels.Any(v => letter == v));

// We create a list that looks like we expect it to if its correct order
var expectedResult = vowelList.OrderBy(x => x);

// We check if we have a result in the expected order
bool isOrdered = vowelList.SequenceEqual(expectedResult);
```

This could be implemented as an extension method on string like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    static readonly List<char> _vowels = new List<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    public static bool VowelsOrdered(this string word)
    {
        var vowelList = word.Where(letter => _vowels.Any(v => letter == v));
        var expectedResult = vowelList.OrderBy(x => x);

        return vowelList.SequenceEqual(expectedResult);
    }

    // Could also be implemented with a lower complexity like this
    public static bool VowelsOrdered2(this string word)
    {
        char last = _vowels[0];
        foreach (var c in word)
        {
            if (_vowels.Any(x => x == c))
            {
                if (c < last)
                    return false;
                else
                    last = c;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then usage would be like:

```
string word = "testing";
bool isOrdered = word.VowelsOrdered();
```